# Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

I'm having trouble with this piece of code. In my DB I have the Passphase column set to binary(20). To get the code listed below I was following a tutorial, but I adjusted quite a bit to fit my needs. My problem is that I don't know how to store the password as binary and not nvarchar.

This is for a registration page to an SQL server if that makes a difference.

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegDNMembershipConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    string insCmd = "Insert into Accounts (AccountName, Passphrase, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) VALUES (@AccountName,@Passphrase,@EmailAddress,@FullName,@Country)";
    SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", TextBoxUN.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passphrase", TextBoxPass.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", TextBoxEA.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBoxFN.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: I'm glad to add `VALUES` part now `:)` What is the value of `TextBoxPass.Text` exactly? Looks like your value doesn't fit for your column type.

Comment: You are trying to send a `varchar` value to a `binary` typed column.  You will need to convert the data in `TextBoxPass.Text` before submitting it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Evan, however I know that is what needs to be done. It says it in the error. Unfortunately I'm new to all of this and I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: My bad, I should read the entire question before commenting ;)  You did state your intent.

Comment: Soner, what do you mean what is the value of TextBoxPass.Text? I just added this with Visual Studio 2012 as TextBox in the Tools section.

Comment: Why is the Passphase column set to `binary(20)` if it contains a string?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're wanting to change this:

```
insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passphrase", TextBoxPass.Text);
```

to this:

```
insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passphrase",
    Encoding.Default.GetBytes(TextBoxPass.Text));
```

Further, please honor the `IDisposable` interface. The code you have above would more appropriately be written:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegDNMembershipConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    string insCmd = "Insert into Accounts (AccountName, Passphrase, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) VALUES (@AccountName,@Passphrase,@EmailAddress,@FullName,@Country)";
    using (var insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SqlParameter insertUser = new SqlParameter("@Passphrase",SqlDbType.Binary, 15);
 insertUser.Value = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBoxPass.Text);
 insCmd.Parameters.Add(insertUser);
```